# istream overloading when referencing another class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have been stuck on what to do with this for loop inside an istream operator, i dont understand why it doesnt find >> operator.

Error C2679 binary '>>': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'Result' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

any help would be madly appreciated.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "Unit.h"
#include "Registration.h"

istream & operator >>(istream & input, Unit & U);
ostream & operator <<(ostream & os, const Unit & U);

istream & operator >>(istream & input, Result & Re);
ostream & operator <<(ostream & os, const Result & Re);

istream & operator >>(istream & input, Date & D);
ostream & operator <<(ostream & os, const Date & D);

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n"; 

    ifstream infile("rinput.txt");
    if (!infile)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    Registration R;

    infile >> R;

    ofstream ofile("routput.txt");

    ofile << R
        << "Number of units = " << R.getCount() << '\n'
        << "Total credits     = " << R.GetCredits() << '\n';

    infile.close();
    ofile.close();

}


#include "Registration.h"

using namespace std;

Registration::Registration()
{

}

istream & operator >>(istream & input, Registration & R)
{
    long idTemp;
    unsigned semesterTemp, countTemp;
    Registration regTemp;
    Result tempResult;

    input >> idTemp >> semesterTemp >> countTemp;

    regTemp.setStudentId(idTemp);
    regTemp.setSemester(semesterTemp);
    regTemp.setCount(countTemp);

        for (unsigned i = 0; i < R.getCount(); i++)
        {       

//THIS LINE IS THE ERROR
            input >> tempResult;
            R.setResult(i, tempResult);
        }       

    return input;
}


//result h file has the following

#ifndef RESULT_H
#define RESULT_H

#include "Date.h"
#include "Unit.h"

class Result
{
public:
    Result();

    float getMark() const;
    void setMark(float mrk);

    int GetCredits() const;

    const Date & getDate() const;
    void setDate(const Date &D);

    const Unit & getUnit() const;
    void setUnit(const Unit &U);

private:
    float mark;
    Date dateObject;
    Unit unitObject;
};


#endif // !RESULT_H
```

this is the error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2679   binary '>>': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'Result' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

each class that is referenced inside result also has an overloading input stream function.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but why is `tempResult` made `static`?

Comment: More related to your problem, you say (in the code as a comment) "This part is in my main file". What do you mean by that? Are those declarations in a header file that you include, or in a different source file? Please try to create a [mcve] to show us.

Comment: they are placed above my int main()

Comment: they need to be declared before they are used, not in your main file

Comment: where should i place them? i thought at the start of the program it is declared? i recently had them in each class and use the friend syntax

Comment: You still haven't put the declarations in header files. They only exist in your "main" source file, no other source file will know about them.

Comment: are you ona bout including all the #include "classname.h"?? because the way the program is designed is to not have main access them directly, it has to go through results.  i need to only includ registration.h

Comment: Before you can use *any* function, normal or overloaded operator, it needs to be *declared*. If you declare in once source file but use in a different, then the different source file doesn't have the declaration. Like I said in my answer, two different translation units are really different translation units. Declarations in one translation unit are declared in that translation unit *only*. The operator declarations needs to be available in *all* source file that use the operators. That's why you need to put them in a header file that all source files include.

Comment: We still need a [mcve], unless you have `using namespace std` in a header file somewhere your code doesn't compile, if you do have that it is quite possibly causing your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example

```
   namespace Me {

 class A 
 {
    // bla
 };

 std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, A& const& obj)
{
   // print in terms of public interface of A
// (else, deckare this a friend function inside A)
return os;
} 

 } // Me

 int main()
{
  std::cout << A(); // operator<<(ostream&, A const&) is the best match
}
```

Answer (score 1):

C++ doesn't really have "source" or "header" files, it deals only with [*translation units*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)).

A translation unit is, in short, a single source file with all included header files. Most importantly, a translation unit is its own independent unit, without any knowledge of other translation units.

That means declarations put in one translation unit (source file) will now be known by a different translation unit.

For a declaration to be known to all translation units that are linked into the final executable program, you should put them in a *header file* that is included everywhere needed.

---

Example:

Header file `result.h`:

```
#ifndef RESULT_H
#define RESULT_H

class Result
{
    // ...
};

std::istream & operator >>(std::istream & input, Result & C);
std::ostream & operator <<(std::ostream & os, const Result & C);

#endif
```

"Main" source file `main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "result.h"    // "Import" the `operator>>` declaration

int main()
{
    Result result;
    std::cin >> result;
}
```

"Result" class implementation source file `result.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include "result.h"

// Result class implementation...

std::istream & operator >>(std::istream & input, Result & C)
{
    // Read input...

    return input;
}
```

When building the above example, you build the two source files separately as two separate translation units. The result of each translation unit is an object file. Then you link those two object files into the executable file.

Comment: cheers man, this makes more sense when you say it like that, i will give this ago and get back to you. thanks bro

Comment: so unfortunately i still get the error,no operator ">>"matches these operands

Comment: @Getwrong Then please (as I mentioned before) create a [mcve] to show us. Also copy-paste the *full* and *complete* output of the compiler into your question, including any possible informational notes (as those often can contain hints about what's happening).

Comment: okay ill edit it

Comment: i updated it, sorry if my explanation is bad im still learning D:. i appreciate your help